# How to show small values in Flot Pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have simple data: `[{"label":"Test 1","data":1332},{"label":"Test 2","data":56187},{"label":"Test 3","data":2},{"label":"Test 4","data":2},{"label":"Test 5","data":42946},{"label":"Test 6","data":1}]` and when i trying to show it in the pie chart i get only only `Test 1`, `Test 2`, `Test 5`.

[image: Pie]

How to show other values?

P.S.
With the old flash chart i had something like this 
[image: flash]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72927014/2358409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't; breaking out labels to series that are too small to see otherwise isn't something that Flot's pie plugin currently supports.

You might suggest this as an enhancement on the Flot [issue tracker](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues).