# How to show small values in a chart.js pie chart

Tags: tensorflow, javascript, html, css, frontend

I am having trouble displaying small values in my chart.js chart. My issue is very similar to a question asked here:
[How to show small values in Flot Pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947521/how-to-show-small-values-in-flot-pie-chart)

Does anyone know if there is a workaround in chart.js?

Comment: You could try to use `chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels` (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) and define a `dataset` with same `data` but  `weight: 0` for displaying small values outside of the chart.

```
{
  data: data,
  weight: 0,      
  borderWidth: 20,
  datalabels: {
    formatter: v => v < 5 ? v : ''
  }
}
```

Then also add a `datalabels.formatter` to the original `dataset` and make sure, it returns an empty `string` for small values.

```
datalabels: {
  textAlign: 'center',
  formatter: v => v < 5 ? '' : v
}
```

Please take a look at the runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
const data = [48, 56, 3, 1, 44];

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
new Chart('myChart', {
  //change to 'doughnut' if your target chart is 'doughnut'
  //type: 'doughnut',
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'gray'],
    datasets: [{
        data: data,
        weight: 0,      
        borderWidth: 20,
        datalabels: {
          formatter: v => v < 5 ? v : ''
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'My Dataset',
        data: data,
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)', 'rgba(145, 90, 185, 0.2)', 'rgba(124, 124, 124, 0.2)'],
        datalabels: {
          textAlign: 'center',
          formatter: v => v < 5 ? '' : v
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="300"></canvas>
```